# Insert an item into the inner RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have `RecyclerView` that shows another full-height `RecyclerView`s as items. And I need to insert a new item in inner `RecylerView` adapter. I wrote a method in the adapter of top level `RecyclerView`:

```
public void notifyInnerItemInserted(final int position, final int insertPosition) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);

    if(holder != null) {
        Day day = records.get(position);
        holder.mAdapter.clear();
        holder.mAdapter.addAll(day.getItems());
        holder.mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(insertPosition);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. And even if I try to update a whole item of top level: `dayAdapter.notifyDataItemInserted(position);` it doesn't work all same. It looks like `RecyclerView` holds old drawable cache. Below a full code of top level adapter:

```
public class DayAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DayAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    public DayAdapter(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.li_day, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Day day = records.get(position);
        List<Record> items = day.mItems;

        if(items == null || items.size() == 0) {
            holder.mContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.mContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.mAdapter.clear();
            holder.mAdapter.addAll(day.getItems());
            holder.mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private RecyclerView mContent;
        private Adapter mAdapter = new Adapter();

        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mContent = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rvContent);
            mContent.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
            FullExpandedListManager lm = new FullExpandedListManager(mContent.getContext());
            SimpleItemDecoration decoration = new SimpleItemDecoration(mContent.getContext(),
                    SimpleItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST);
            mContent.setLayoutManager(lm);
            mContent.addItemDecoration(decoration);
            mContent.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    }

    public static class Day extends BaseAdapter.Record<Day> {
        private List<Record> mItems;

        public List<Record> getItems() {
            return mItems;
        }

        public Day setItems(List<Record> items) {
            mItems = items;
            return this;
        }
    }

    public void notifyInnerItemInserted(final int position, final int insertPosition) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);

        if(holder != null) {
            holder.mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(insertPosition);
        }
    }
}
```

What do I doing wrong? How to fix my solution?

Comment: Please include more info about the error instead of just "What do I doing wrong".

Comment: There are no errors. Just it does nothing. The inner `RecyclerView` doesn't show a new item.

Comment: Can you post the adapter code?

Comment: I posted it already. Inner adapter works perfectly, I use it in another fragments